Quitar signos diacríticos a un texto en Visual Basic.Net (VB.NET)
Necesito eliminar los signos diacríticos a un texto y lo necesito en VB.NET. Lo tengo hecho en C# pero solo del acento agudo y lo necesitaría hacer desde el u0300 al u036F.
Mi código en C#:
string textoNormalizado = texto.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormD);    
textResult = textoNormalizado.Replace("\u0301", ""); //COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT

Lo necesitaría en VB.NET y de todos los signos diacríticos sin tener que ir uno a uno.

Si es en vb.net, las otras dos etiquetas sobran.. y cual es el problema?? no podes hacer un procedimiento que lo haga? un for? hasta un replace se podria usar, ya que todos empiezan igual y miden lo mismo, no?

Del u0300 al u036F, es lo mismo que decir desde 719 hasta 879 en decimal.
Por lo que para remover esos caracteres puedes hacer:
C#:
string textoNormalizado = new(texto.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormD).Where(t => !(t>= 719 && t<=879)).ToArray());

VB.net:
Dim textoNormalizado As New String(texto.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormD).Where(Function(t) Not (AscW(t) >= 719 AndAlso AscW(t) <= 879)).ToArray())


Por otro lado, me parece que lo que tu quieres remover son lo caracteres categorizados como Mark, Nonspacing, que es una lista más amplia pero incluye los que tu mencionas. En tal caso puedes hacer:
C#
string textoNormalizado = new( texto.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormD).Where(t => CharUnicodeInfo.GetUnicodeCategory(t) != UnicodeCategory.NonSpacingMark).ToArray());

VB.net:
Dim textoNormalizado As New String(texto.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormD).Where(Function(t) CharUnicodeInfo.GetUnicodeCategory(t) <> UnicodeCategory.NonSpacingMark).ToArray())


Había visto esta forma, pero no llega a funcionar, no se si falte algo. textResult = textoNormalizado.Replace("/[\u0300-\u036f]/g", "");

ehhhh pero si arriba en mi respuesta te señalo como hacerlo
